Apache jclouds - service loader error when used in Android
I am trying to use Apache's jclouds toolkit (https://jclouds.apache.org/) for uploading files to AWS or Azure storage. Specifically I want to do this in an Android app.
I am using Android Studio IDE for development, using Gradle for build and writing everything in Kotlin.
jclouds works absolutely fine when I just run a main() script from the IDE. I can upload files to Azure or AWS fine. A minimal example (in Kotlin), that doesn't upload but illustrates the problem, is:
import org.jclouds.providers.Providers

fun main() {
    println(Providers.all().map{it.id}.toSet())
}

>> [aws-s3, azureblob, b2, google-cloud-storage, rackspace-cloudfiles-us, rackspace-cloudfiles-uk]

which simply lists all the cloud providers jcloud's supports.
When I try to run the same code from my app I get problems. First, the APK build fails because of multiple/duplicate META-INF/DEPENDENCIES paths:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction
   > 21 files found with path 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES' from inputs:
      - /Users/senparsons/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/3a6b0c849edb2a98ffcd0988e9962ed2/transformed/jetified-jclouds-allblobstore-2.6.0.jar
      - /Users/senparsons/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/f66b159f397ffa685234aaf7f817ecf2/transformed/jetified-aws-s3-2.6.0.jar
      - /Users/senparsons/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/16dd5496f82c90f4c1357b5d6d3fca4e/transformed/jetified-s3-2.6.0.jar

[.... etc]


When I fix this in my app's build.gradle file with:
   packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'META-INF/AL2.0'
        pickFirst 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        // required to allow to build with jcloud (due to jetified-xxx dependencies):
        merge 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES*'
        merge 'META-INF/LICENSE.md'
        merge 'META-INF/NOTICE.md'
    }

the app builds, but when I call in the app,
 Providers.all().map{it.id}.toSet()

I get the exception:
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.jclouds.providers.ProviderMetadata: Provider org.jclouds.aws.s3.AWSS3ProviderMetadata could not be instantiated
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:233)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:183)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:392)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:416)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:494)
        at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableCollection$Builder.addAll(ImmutableCollection.java:433)
        at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableCollection$ArrayBasedBuilder.addAll(ImmutableCollection.java:538)
        at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet$Builder.addAll(ImmutableSet.java:527)
        at org.jclouds.providers.Providers.all(Providers.java:83)

[... etc ....]

        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
     Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.jclouds.JcloudsVersion.get(JcloudsVersion.java:153)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.jclouds.apis.internal.BaseApiMetadata.defaultProperties(BaseApiMetadata.java:84)
        at org.jclouds.apis.internal.BaseApiMetadata$Builder.<init>(BaseApiMetadata.java:111)
        at org.jclouds.rest.internal.BaseHttpApiMetadata$Builder.<init>(BaseHttpApiMetadata.java:77)
        at org.jclouds.s3.S3ApiMetadata$Builder.<init>(S3ApiMetadata.java:100)
        at org.jclouds.aws.s3.AWSS3ApiMetadata$Builder.<init>(AWSS3ApiMetadata.java:60)
        at org.jclouds.aws.s3.AWSS3ApiMetadata.<init>(AWSS3ApiMetadata.java:44)
        at org.jclouds.aws.s3.AWSS3ProviderMetadata$Builder.<init>(AWSS3ProviderMetadata.java:113)
        at org.jclouds.aws.s3.AWSS3ProviderMetadata.builder(AWSS3ProviderMetadata.java:59)
        at org.jclouds.aws.s3.AWSS3ProviderMetadata.<init>(AWSS3ProviderMetadata.java:68)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:388)
            ... 42 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: META-INF/maven/org.apache.jclouds/jclouds-core/pom.properties
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:907)
        at org.jclouds.JcloudsVersion.readVersionPropertyFromClasspath(JcloudsVersion.java:87)
        at org.jclouds.JcloudsVersion.<init>(JcloudsVersion.java:82)
        at org.jclouds.JcloudsVersion.<init>(JcloudsVersion.java:77)
        at org.jclouds.JcloudsVersion.<clinit>(JcloudsVersion.java:48)
            ... 54 more

From what I understand, jclouds uses java 'service loaders' to loader 'metadata' classes for each provider (AWS, Azure, etc.). i.e. The service loader, loads a metadata class (e.g. org.jclouds.aws.s3.AWSS3ProviderMetadata) that implements the org.jclouds.providers.ProviderMetadata interface. As this metadata class is required to do everything related it's provider (including upload to storage) this is not just a problem of getting a list of provider strings.
So, what is causing the service loader problem? Where have my metadata classes gone to? Is it to do with the META-INF/DEPENDENCIES files? From what I understand the service loaders user files in META-INF/SERVICES. The nearest related post I can find is Jclouds with multiple providers but this hasn't helped me much other than identifying the problem.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.
FYI, my only jclouds import (in build.gradle) is:
implementation 'org.apache.jclouds:jclouds-allblobstore:2.6.0'


Related issue ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCLOUDS-747?jql=text%20~%20%22jcloud%20android%22

So, after some digging I have found the root of the problem. If you look at the bottom of the stack trace (from the question above), you find:
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: META-INF/maven/org.apache.jclouds/jclouds-core/pom.properties
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:907)
        at org.jclouds.JcloudsVersion.readVersionPropertyFromClasspath(JcloudsVersion.java:87)
        at org.jclouds.JcloudsVersion.<init>(JcloudsVersion.java:82)
        at org.jclouds.JcloudsVersion.<init>(JcloudsVersion.java:77)
        at org.jclouds.JcloudsVersion.<clinit>(JcloudsVersion.java:48)
            ... 54 more

Apparently everytime jclouds initiate a service provider (e.g. org.jclouds.aws.s3.AWSS3ProviderMetadata) it tries to create an instance of JcloudsVersion and to do this it needs to read the version info contained in META-INF/maven/org.apache.jclouds/jclouds-core/pom.properties. Now why you need the version object, and why version is kept in a pom file, is anyone's guess. But the fact is, that this file will not be included in the APK unless you specify this in the app's build.gradle:
packagingOptions {
    merge 'META-INF/maven/org.apache.jclouds/jclouds-core/pom.properties'
}

Then the services providers load!
Of course, now there are other errors when I try to actually create a BlobStoreContext from one of the services but that is another story.
